# Plesk 12 Debian 7 MySQL : CPU usage is too high

Tags: mysql, cpu, plesk, my.cnf

I have a problem with MySQL and MySQL CPU usage at Plesk.
I have a news site with Joomla, and about 100-150 online user.

```
CPU: AMD Opteron(tm) Processor 6366 HE 3 core
Memory: 4GB
HDD: 250 GB
Plesk 12 licence
Debian 7
```

My site is very slow, it opens about 10-12 sec. my pages, I see MySQL CPU usage is about 85.2%, when there are 148 user online at same time...

Can anyone help me about MySQL settings? I wouldn't like to believe that server is weak for about 1000 online users....

Here is my MySQL config: [my.cnf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4SB8sCVq_5fR21pOWVrUGt2SlU/view?usp=sharing)

What can I setup with that for good working?

Comment: I think your question is not about programming and there is not any tried code that we could help you on it, So migrate your question to [DBA Site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site, It will make more sense there ;).

Comment: i'll write it to those page, hope it can be help anyone.